# How to separate value of column to become column?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

My data frame is so dirty, it put my interesting variable together.

my df like it :
[image]

```
      eid                                edu
1 1009467 "A levels/AS levels or equivalent"
2 1016906 "A levels/AS levels or equivalent"
3 1018742 "A levels/AS levels or equivalent"
4 1030778 "A levels/AS levels or equivalent","CSEs or equivalent"
5 1030785 "A levels/AS levels or equivalent","CSEs or equivalent"
```

or you can copy it:

```
structure(list(n = 399:401, edu = c("\"A levels/AS levels or equivalent\",\"College or University degree\",\"CSEs or equivalent\",\"NVQ or HND or HNC or equivalent\"", 
"\"A levels/AS levels or equivalent\",\"College or University degree\",\"CSEs or equivalent\",\"NVQ or HND or HNC or equivalent\",\"O levels/GCSEs or equivalent\"", 
"\"A levels/AS levels or equivalent\",\"College or University degree\",\"CSEs or equivalent\",\"NVQ or HND or HNC or equivalent\",\"O levels/GCSEs or equivalent\""
)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data. Frame")
```

and it may be contain 8 education level options:

```
"A levels/AS levels or equivalent",
"College or University degree",
"CSEs or equivalent",
"NVQ or HND or HNC or equivalent",
"O levels/GCSEs or equivalent",
"Other professional qualifications eg: nursing, teaching",
"Prefer not to answer",
"None of the above"
```

The dirtiest thing is that it may appear at the same time, the first five are selected together.

I want to separate my column of edu according their value to become new variable, and if edu contain it , it will display 1, if not, it will display 0

like it:

```
      eid                                edu 
1 1009467 "A levels/AS levels or equivalent"           
2 1016906 "A levels/AS levels or equivalent"           
3 1018742 "A levels/AS levels or equivalent"           
4 1030778 "A levels/AS levels or equivalent","CSEs or equivalent"        
5 1043561 "A levels/AS levels or equivalent","CSEs or equivalent"       

A levels CSEs
1        0
1        0
1        0
1        1
1        1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please share sample data as copy/pasteable text we can run code on (e.g., `dput(your_data[1:5, c("eid", "edu", "CSEs or equivalent", "Prefer")])` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 5 rows of those columns). We can't test code on a screenshot.

Comment: @GregorThomas I am dput(a1[1:2, c("n", "edu")])
it show:structure(list(n = 399:400, edu = c("\"A levels/AS levels or equivalent\",\"College or University degree\",\"CSEs or equivalent\",\"NVQ or HND or HNC or equivalent\"", 
"\"A levels/AS levels or equivalent\",\"College or University degree\",\"CSEs or equivalent\",\"NVQ or HND or HNC or equivalent\",\"O levels/GCSEs or equivalent\""
)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data. Frame") . Is this the sample you need?

Comment: That is great, yes. I need to go to bed now, but if you edit that `dput` output into your question it will make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: @GregorThomas OK, Let's me trying it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr) #>= 1.1.0
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(edu, sep = ",") %>% 
  mutate(edu =  gsub("^\"|\"$", "",edu)) %>% 
  mutate(A_levels = ifelse(edu %in% "A levels/AS levels or equivalent", 1, 0),
         College_Uni = ifelse(edu %in% "College or University degree", 1, 0),
         CSEs = ifelse(edu %in% "CSEs or equivalent", 1, 0),
         NVQ_HND_HNC = ifelse(edu %in% "NVQ or HND or HNC or equivalent", 1, 0),
         O_levels_GCSEs = ifelse(edu %in% "O levels/GCSEs or equivalent", 1, 0),
         Other_prof_qual = ifelse(edu %in% "Other professional qualifications eg: nursing, teaching", 1, 0),
         Prefer_not_to_answer = ifelse(edu %in% "Prefer not to answer", 1, 0),
         None_of_the_above = ifelse(edu %in% "None of the above", 1, 0)) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~max(.)), .by = eid)
```

```
 eid edu                              A_levels Colleg…¹  CSEs NVQ_H…² O_lev…³ Other…⁴ Prefe…⁵ None_…⁶
    <int> <chr>                               <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1009467 A levels/AS levels or equivalent        1        0     0       0       0       0       0       0
2 1016906 A levels/AS levels or equivalent        1        0     0       0       0       0       0       0
3 1018742 A levels/AS levels or equivalent        1        0     0       0       0       0       0       0
4 1030778 CSEs or equivalent                      1        0     1       0       0       0       0       0
5 1030785 CSEs or equivalent                      1        0     1       0       0       0       0       0
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​College_Uni, ²​NVQ_HND_HNC, ³​O_levels_GCSEs, ⁴​Other_prof_qual,
#   ⁵​Prefer_not_to_answer, ⁶​None_of_the_above
```

Comment: Thank you! I also think use mutate and ifelse function, but I can't write.

Comment: Hi, I found that there will be a problem with separate_rows(edu, sep = ","), because I have "," in my "Other professional qualifications eg: nursing, teaching", so I run table(df$Other_prof_qual), it will show everyone is 0. I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: No problem, just do it like this : `df %>% 
  separate_rows(edu, sep = '\\",') %>%`

Comment: Thank you. I am do my way :`Other_prof_qual = ifelse(edu %in% c("Other professional qualifications eg: nursing", "teaching"), 1, 0)`   and it's result same your way.